# Modifying $PATH for PHP system() calls

Tags: php, macos, shell, path, system

I need to modify the $PATH on my mac so that PHP system() calls will recognize it.

So far I've edited the /etc/profile to include the line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

but if I do `system('echo $PATH');` in PHP the new path doesn't show up.

Comment: Did you restart the shell (e.g. log out/back in) to get the new profile settings?

Comment: @Marc B- yes, restarted.

Comment: Make sure that the shell PHP is using for the exec call actually uses /etc/profile. subshells may ignore it.

Comment: @Marc B- good point, I'll look into it

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137726/creating-permanent-executable-aliases).

Answer (score 2):

Use the putenv function. For example, to add the current directory to the $PATH, one could use the following code :

```
<?php
putenv('PATH='.getenv('PATH').':.');   
echo shell_exec('echo $PATH'); /* Prints the expected result */
```

http://php.net/putenv

Comment: @Artefact2- Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to modify the system environment permanently, not through code.