# Why is this shell script not running as expected from PHP?

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, shell-exec

I have this PHP program in /var/www folder to run a shell script and load the HTML file created by that shell script. If I run the shell script manually from command line then it works like charm but when run via PHP program from browser then it only creates an empty file.

PHP CODE

```
$a = './script.sh '.$foo.' '.$bar;
$b = shell_exec($a);
include '/var/tmp/reports/r.html';
```

SHELL SCRIPT

```
cat file.ext | awk <something with $foo and $bar> | command > /var/tmp/reports/r.html
```

*(Edit ^ "file.ext" is actually a .log file. It iss located in /var/log/.. And "command" is an other program that creates an .html file from that log file)*

Permissions of my files are :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc    www-data   848 Feb 13 10:43 php.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu www-data   230 Feb 13 10:51 script.sh*
```

And /var/tmp/reports/r.html doesn't exist before execution of PHP.
After execution of script directly via command line it creates r.html file like :

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 121884 Feb 13 11:42 r.html
```

But when script is executed via PHP from browser it creates an empty file like this

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data      0 Feb 13 11:43 r.html
```

Edit1 : On @lurker's suggestio I tried changing script.sh to

```
#!/bin/sh

cat file.log | awk '{if(substr($5,2)>="'$1'" && substr($5,2)<="'$2'")print $0}' | awk 'gsub(",", "", $1);' | /usr/bin/command > /var/tmp/reports/r.html
```

It also generated an empty file only.

Edit2 : I changed the script to ->

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo echo "sdfsf" > /var/tmp/reports/r.html
```

Even it wont work.

Comment: `shell_exec($output)` ... what's `$output`? Shouldn't it be `shell_exec($a)`?

Comment: @lurker oops! I corrected that!

Comment: Where is `file.ext` located? And is `command` defined in a PATH that PHP is operating with? It looks like `./script.sh` is executing, but something is failing in the command string inside the script, so the `> ...` is creating the file, but the execution of what fills it up is failing.

Comment: "file.ext" is actually a .log file. its located in /var/log/.. And "command" is an other program that creates an .html file from that log file

Comment: Right. I was suggesting that maybe `script.sh` didn't know where it was when executed from PHP. Where is `command` defined? It might be in your PATH when running from the shell, but not in the PATH that PHP sees when it executes. Those PATHs are different. In your `script.sh`, you should try, `/path/to/command` in place of `command` to see if that solves it (`/path/to` is the full path that `command` is found in).

Comment: You may have problems with the usage of variables in `awk`. What if you show the code of the `awk` part?

Comment: How do I set the path for this? Should I do something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144238/modifying-path-for-php-system-calls

Comment: @fedorqui the script works like a charm if I execute it directly from command line like ./script.sh

Any way awk thing is like -> | awk '{if(substr($5,2)>="'$1'" && substr($5,2)<="'$2'")print $0}' | awk 'gsub(",", "", $1);' |

Comment: @SumitSinha the thing with `awk` scripts is that they may need `$i` to be escaped to work if called from another platform like PHP: `\$i`, etc.

Comment: @fedorqui Tried. It wont work even then.

Comment: @SumitSinha yes, you could modify the path from PHP, or I think it would as good to update the path from within `script.sh`, or just reference the command by its full path as I indicated in my last comment.

Comment: @lurker I tried your suggestion. I gave me same empty file as earlier.

Comment: Please show what you tried by adding it to your problem statement. It's not clear to me what your updated code looks like. Also, not knowing what the PATH is in PHP, maybe it can't find `awk` either? Hard to say without knowing what the PATH is. Try a test case, too, by removing `awk` from your script temporarily and just `cat` a file to the output and see if that works. In other words, break the problem down by process of elimination so you can determine where it is.

Comment: Sure! please see the Edit in the bottom of the question above.

Comment: See additional information in my answer. I'm pretty sure it's a PATH issue, and it's unclear how restricted the default PATH is in your PHP environment. I also offered some debug tips in my prior comment.

Comment: @lurker Thanks dear! I am trying those tips of yours .

Comment: Do you have permission to run that command? Maybe the user owner of the script is not in sudoers.

Comment: 'ubuntu' user, the owner of script, is in sudoers. I even tried changing the owner of php program to 'ubuntu' . But then it won't even create an empty file

Comment: What are the permissions on the `/var/tmp/reports` directory?

Comment: @lurker Permissions for reports directory are `drwxrwxrwx  2 root   root       4096 Feb 15 10:21 reports/` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the command `cat file.ext | awk <something with $foo and $bar> | command > /var/tmp/reports/r.html`, when I executed it from `script.sh` directly then it approached the `file.ext` as `ubuntu`user. `ubuntu` user was authorized to access `file.ext`, since it belonged to the group that could read it. But when I executed the command form `php.php` script via browser then it accessed `file.ext` as `abc` user (`abc` was actually `www-data` user of apache2). Neither the `abc` user (I mean www-data user) belong to the group which could access the file nor did the file allowed `other users` to read it. Hence the php script failed to produce the proper output.