# How to restart a rails server on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Locally I just interrupt (ctrl-c) and then start it again.

How do I do the same thing with an app on heroku?

Comment: Be careful not to over-eagerly translate the development environment's `$ rails restart` into its equivalent on Heroku: `$ heroku rails restart`. This command relies on `spring` which (usually) won't be installed on Heroku. Therefore go with `heroku restart` like the others have said.

Answer (score 473, accepted):

The answer was:

```
heroku restart -a app_name

# The -a is the same as --app
```

Easily aliased with `alias hra='heroku restart --app '`
Which you can make a permanent alias by adding it to your .bashrc or .bash_aliases file as described at:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias and
[Creating permanent executable aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137726/creating-permanent-executable-aliases)
Then you can just type `hra app_name`

You can restart a specific remote, e.g. "staging" with:

```
heroku restart -a app_name -r remote_name
```

Alternatively if you are in the root directory of your rails application you can just type

```
heroku restart
```

to restart that app and and you can create an easy alias for that with

```
alias hr='heroku restart'`
```

You can place these aliases in your `.bashrc` file or (preferred) in a `.bash_aliases` file which is called from `.bashrc`

Comment: Also, if you're getting the message `No web processes running` -- that's because you're on zero dynos -- log in to heroku and scale up your app -- that's how I landed on this question.

Comment: If you have multiple heroku remotes for your app, such as a staging or production environment, you'll need to run the following from your app root: `heroku restart -r <name of heroku remote>`, for instance `heroku restart -r production`

Comment: eh, why it's not on `-h` listing.

Answer (score 38):

Go into your application directory on terminal and run following command:

```
heroku restart
```

Answer (score 24):

If you have several heroku apps, you must type  `heroku restart --app app_name` or `heroku restart -a app_name`

Comment: The syntax is wrong, should be heroku restart -a appname

Comment: That was an old answer, just that.

Answer (score 17):

Just type the following commands from console.

```
cd /your_project
heroku restart
```

Answer (score 16):

```
heroku ps:restart [web|worker] --app app_name
```

works for all processes declared in your Procfile. So if you have multiple web processes or worker processes, each labeled with a number, you can selectively restart one of them:

```
heroku ps:restart web.2 --app app_name
heroku ps:restart worker.3 --app app_name
```