# How can i send an email on cp (copy) or rm (remove) command in linux

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, administrator

I want to send an email when someone runs specific command on linux like cp (copy) or rm(remove) command.Can anybody tell me how it is possible ?

Comment: Yes i am trying to achieve this. if you have any idea how  i can do give me an idea  then i will do

Answer (score 2):

You can use aliases: [Creating permanent executable aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137726/creating-permanent-executable-aliases)

For example you can add in your ~/.bashrc :

```
alias rm='my_script.sh'
```

where `my_script.sh` is a script which can send an email.